# What's does a server receive in an image request from email?

Tags: image, email, request

Take this scenario:

1. I send an HTML email with images embedded in it - such as a newsletter with images placed inside using an  tag.
2. I open the email
3. An image is requested

During that image request, what is the full set of information sent to the server?  Can someone paste it in?

Would love to see the full request & header when the email is opened in a client like Outlook and at least one webmail platform like Gmail.

As to the comment about *which server* -- I guess HTTP?  If I'm viewing an email in Gmail, and an  tag is served, that is being served over HTTP, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about, you know, actually trying it yourself?

Comment: BTW, you should also specify *which* server (HTTP, POP, FTP...) you are talking about and how you are sending the images. As attachments? As links to a web page?

Comment: I don't know how, or I would.  Hey, just a front-end guy.

I'll modify the question per your second point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the client computer is concerned, mail client applications are completely different from a web-based mail front-end.

Typically, mail client applications (formally [Mail User Agents or MUAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_client)) use a mail-specific protocol such as [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) to access a mailbox on a remote server.

Depending on the capabilities of the protocol, the MUA may have to download a whole message before displaying anything (POP3) or it may be able to request each [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) attachment separately (IMAP). Usually images are included as MIME attachments and are encoded in a printable form (i.e. restricted to [7-bit ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) using something like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), in order to ensure delivery without corruption.

Web-based mail front-ends, on the other hand, are accessed through the generic [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) protocol - the message decoding happens at the remote server. Images are retrieved through normal [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Request_methods) requests like every other image.

A few years back, you might have been able to see both cases at work using a network sniffer tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). These days most decent mail providers prefer the encrypted versions of these protocols (POP3S, IMAPS and [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)) which cannot be usefully studied using a network sniffer.

If you really wish to have a look at the protocols, you might still be able to find a POP3/IMAP service that allows unencrypted connections, although it's probably not going to be a big provider. You could also set-up [your own server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop3s#Server_implementations) for experimentation.

If you use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/), on the other hand, there is at least [one add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) that allows you to see the requests made by the browser, by intercepting the requests before they are encrypted. It will allow you to see what happens as you use e.g. Gmail.