# Request an image to a server side language, in an HTML Email

Tags: html, firebase-realtime-database

In an HTML Email, is it possible to request (GET) an image file, when the **src** is a web address like:

```
www.example.com/returnImage123
```

And a server side language reads the string "returnImage123" and returns an image file like:

```
www.example.com/images/image123.jpg
```

I have looked for a solution but I only find Javascript based solutions, which don't work in an HTML email. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023098/whats-does-a-server-receive-in-an-image-request-from-email), it is clarified that an HTML email requests (GET) embedded image files using HTTP protocol.

Please advice! Thanks

Comment: You may need to look into maybe doing a redirect to `image123.jpg` from `returnImage123`. But why not just use `image123.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. With your particular example, it seems the easiest solution is to just use URL re-writing. Although, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just put the actual link in the email. At any rate, you could also hit a server-side endpoint - CGI or REST or whatever and that just returns you the image. You could also do both - hit `www.example.com/returnImage123` which gets rewritten as `www.example.com/imageScript.php?file=image123` and then the PHP file takes over and uses the $_GET to determine what to return.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the `javascript` tag belongs here. You're better off tagging with the technologies you use. Unless you use JS for your backend, in which case, you probably need to tag with `node.js` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Adjit, the reason is that I'm working on an email image file transferring service (like WeTransfer) where images are embedded in the email, but the the files expire after 7 days. So I need to return a placeholder image, and this placeholder will be different every time a user opens the email (as they include advertisements about our service)

Comment: Thanks @vlaz, I'm using Google Firebase as a backend (Javascript), I'm sorry I didn't clarify this. But I can work on a Meteor/PHP/Node solution if necessary.